# How to update 2 arrays elements within a document based on certain conditions

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, updates

I have a document that consists of 2 arrays, I am trying to update particular array element of both arrays based on some condition at the same time using `$elemMatch`.

Query

```
targetManagementSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
     franchiseeId : franchiseeId,
     'yearlyTarget.year': 2019,
     'quarterlyTarget': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'quarter.from': 7,
            'quarter.to': 9
        }
      },
     'monthlyTarget': {
        $elemMatch: {
           'month': 7
        }
      }
    }, {
    $set: {
        'yearlyTarget.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
        'quarterlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
        'monthlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7
    }
}, (err, updatedTargetRes) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log("error in updating targetsAchieved " + err);
      } else if (updatedTargetRes != null && updatedTargetRes != '') {
         console.log(updatedTargetRes + " :updatedTargetRes");
      } else {
         console.log("target not updated");
      }
})
```

Document before update

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cc6d6151b74b719acd36eaf"),
    "quarterlyTarget": [
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 4,
                "to": 6
            },
            "target": 47000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 7,
                "to": 9
            },
            "target": 51200,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 10,
                "to": 12
            },
            "target": 64000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 1,
                "to": 3
            },
            "target": 35000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        }
    ],
    "monthlyTarget": [
        {
            "month": 1,
            "target": 10000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 2,
            "target": 10000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 3,
            "target": 15000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 4,
            "target": 15500,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 5,
            "target": 15500,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 6,
            "target": 16000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 7,
            "target": 16200,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 8,
            "target": 17000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 9,
            "target": 18000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 10,
            "target": 19000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 11,
            "target": 20000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 12,
            "target": 19000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        }
    ],
    "franchiseeId": "5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21",
    "yearlyTarget": {
        "year": 2019,
        "target": 197200,
        "targetAchieved": 0
    },
    "offer": null,
    "status": "1",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2019-04-29T10:46:45.643Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

Document after update

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cc6d6151b74b719acd36eaf"),
    "quarterlyTarget": [
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 4,
                "to": 6
            },
            "target": 47000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 7,
                "to": 9
            },
            "target": 51200,
            "targetAchieved": 101540.7 //updates successfully
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 10,
                "to": 12
            },
            "target": 64000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "quarter": {
                "from": 1,
                "to": 3
            },
            "target": 35000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        }
    ],
    "monthlyTarget": [
        {
            "month": 1,
            "target": 10000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 2,
            "target": 10000,
            "targetAchieved": 101540.7 //updates here, which is wrong
        },
        {
            "month": 3,
            "target": 15000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 4,
            "target": 15500,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 5,
            "target": 15500,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 6,
            "target": 16000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 7,
            "target": 16200,
            "targetAchieved": 0 //must update the value 101540.7 here
        },
        {
            "month": 8,
            "target": 17000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 9,
            "target": 18000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 10,
            "target": 19000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 11,
            "target": 20000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 12,
            "target": 19000,
            "targetAchieved": 0
        }
    ],
    "franchiseeId": "5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21",
    "yearlyTarget": {
        "year": 2019,
        "target": 197200,
        "targetAchieved": 101540.7
    },
    "offer": null,
    "status": "1",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2019-04-29T10:46:45.643Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

It takes the index of the first match i.e `1` of `quarterlyTarget` array and applies the same to `monthlyTarget` array instead of taking the index based on the condition I have specified. Hence updating the wrong index of the `monthlyTarget` array.

I know this can be achieved using `arrayFilters`, I have done it as well. But the version of mongodb I am using is 3.2 and unfortunately I cannot upgrade it, therefore, I need to work with the method that is supported by 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
viewmultiplrarrayupdate: (callback) => {
    maultipleArrayUpdate.findOneAndUpdate({
      "franchiseeId": '5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21',
      'yearlyTarget.year': 2019,
      'quarterlyTarget': {
        $elemMatch: {
          'quarter.from': 7,
          'quarter.to': 9
        }
      }
    },
      {
        $set: {
          'yearlyTarget.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
          'quarterlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
        }
      }
      , (err, updatedTargetResponse) => {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null)
        }
        else {
          maultipleArrayUpdate.findOneAndUpdate({
            "franchiseeId": '5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21',
            'yearlyTarget.year': 2019,
            'monthlyTarget': {
              $elemMatch: {
                'month': 7
              }
            }
          }, { 'monthlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7 }, (error, updatedTargetRes) => {
            if (error) {
              callback(error, null)
            }
            else {
              callback(null, "successfully updated")
            }
          })
        }
      })
  },
```

Comment: May be this is not the smartest way but is the easiest  way to achieve the desired result avoiding the index problem

Comment: try your find query with `$and` (will make sure all the conditions have to meet the criteria to pull the documents), and instead of using `findAndUpdate` try using just `update` without `upsert`

Comment: @SouravDe I did do it the same way, as that was the only way I found to be working.

Comment: @JBone I have already tried with `$and`, but it did not work. If I use just update it gives me warning, as I am using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

ok you missed the `{upsert:true}`

I ran this query on Mongo Editor and it worked. Let me know if this one works for you  (also know that I used only pasrtial find query since there is only one document. you can go ahead and use the full find block. My focus was on updating the document)

```
db.user_test.findOneAndUpdate(

    {franchiseeId: "5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21", "yearlyTarget.year":2019, "quarterlyTarget": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "quarter.from": 7,
            "quarter.to": 9
        }
      }},

      {
    $set: {
        'yearlyTarget.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
        'quarterlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7,
        'monthlyTarget.$.targetAchieved': 101540.7
    }
}, 

{upsert:true})
```

this is the document I got back once I updated

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1a1212a9eea913c2b8229a"),
    "quarterlyTarget" : [
        {
            "quarter" : {
                "from" : 4,
                "to" : 6
            },
            "target" : 47000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "quarter" : {
                "from" : 7,
                "to" : 9
            },
            "target" : 51200,
            "targetAchieved" : 101540.7
        },
        {
            "quarter" : {
                "from" : 10,
                "to" : 12
            },
            "target" : 64000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "quarter" : {
                "from" : 1,
                "to" : 3
            },
            "target" : 35000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        }
    ],
    "monthlyTarget" : [
        {
            "month" : 1,
            "target" : 10000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 2,
            "target" : 10000,
            "targetAchieved" : 101540.7
        },
        {
            "month" : 3,
            "target" : 15000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 4,
            "target" : 15500,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 5,
            "target" : 15500,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 6,
            "target" : 16000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 7,
            "target" : 16200,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 8,
            "target" : 17000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 9,
            "target" : 18000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 10,
            "target" : 19000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 11,
            "target" : 20000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        },
        {
            "month" : 12,
            "target" : 19000,
            "targetAchieved" : 0
        }
    ],
    "franchiseeId" : "5c42bd6085edaa215cba5a21",
    "yearlyTarget" : {
        "year" : 2019,
        "target" : 197200,
        "targetAchieved" : 101540.7
    },
    "offer" : null,
    "status" : "1",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-04-29T06:46:45.643-04:00"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: this works for me too, but you missed the second `$elemMatch` condition I have given in the query. My problem is the monthly target should update for current month that is `7`, but instead it updates for `2` because it's taking the index of the first matched condition of the first `$elemMatch` of `quarterlyTarget` array. Also I don't want to insert new data, I just want to update existing data, that's why I haven't used `{upsert : true}`